# Using \VerbatimInput with text files that contain Greek and English

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I have to include some text files in my document, which are reports derived from another program.
The text in these files is mixed (Greek and English).

I'm using the `fancyvrb`  package to include the text with the `\VerbatimInput` command and compiling with PDFLaTeX.
The problem I am having is that the output I get does not recognize the Latin characters.

I've attached two pictures which include the verbatim text rendered in the document and the text in the actual file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a MWE of the code I'm using:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

% PACKAGES
% MAIN
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

% MISC.
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% FILE CONTENTS TO INCLUDE IN VERBATIM
\begin{filecontents}{S12RESutf.txt}
1.  a-posteriori μεταβλητότητα = 122.1875
     a-posteriori τυπική απόκλιση =  11.05
     βαθμοί ελευθερίας =    6
     κριτήριο βελτιστοποίησης =   733.1250

2.  OI ΣΥΝΟΡΘΩΜΕΝΕΣ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΙΣ 

σκοπευόμενο  συνορθωμένη  τυπική 
σημείο       διεύθυνση    απόκλιση 
               (grad)      (cc)  

    22        0.00000      6.38
    32       30.69490      6.38
    42       35.08358      6.38
     2      103.23945      6.38
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \attachfile{S12RES.txt} {\bfseries Αποτελέσματα συνόρθωσης σταθμού 12}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{3mm}
    
    \VerbatimInput[baselinestretch=.9]{S12RESutf.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output I'm getting is this]

[image: The contents of the text file]

Comment: Please add to the preamble a portion of the content of the included files using: `\begin{filecontents}{S12RES.txt}
here put the a portion of S12RES.txt
\end{filecontents}`

Comment: I've included the snippet of code you suggested with a portion of the file contents. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mix Greek and Latin alphabets provided the current language uses the Latin alphabet and you load `alphabeta`:

```
% FILE CONTENTS TO INCLUDE IN VERBATIM
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
1.  a-posteriori μεταβλητότητα = 122.1875
     a-posteriori τυπική απόκλιση =  11.05
     βαθμοί ελευθερίας =    6
     κριτήριο βελτιστοποίησης =   733.1250

2.  OI ΣΥΝΟΡΘΩΜΕΝΕΣ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΙΣ 

σκοπευόμενο  συνορθωμένη  τυπική 
σημείο       διεύθυνση    απόκλιση 
               (grad)      (cc)  

    22        0.00000      6.38
    32       30.69490      6.38
    42       35.08358      6.38
     2      103.23945      6.38
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

% PACKAGES
% MAIN
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

% MISC
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\VerbatimInputMixed}[2][]{%
  \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}%
  \VerbatimInput[#1]{#2}%
  \end{otherlanguage*}%
}

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInputMixed[baselinestretch=.9]{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I changed the file name to ensure not clobbering my files and to have them properly grouped. You don't need to use `\jobname`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the non-greek text correctly it must be enclosed, for example, in `\foreignlanguage{english}{non-greek text here}`. (In the MWE below I have used the macro `\texteng` defined with `\newcommand{\texteng}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}`.)

To do this inside `Verbatim` we have to set some escape characters for inserting commands. For example:

```
commandchars=\\\{\}
```

allows you to use the standard characters `\`, `{` and `}` to start a macro and mark the beginning and end of a group. Alternatively, you can also define other special characters, for example:

```
commandchars=+\[\]
```

In this way you can write `\foreignlanguage{english}` inside `Verbatim` with `+foreignlanguage[english]` (se the last example in the code below).

**MWE**

```
% FILE CONTENTS TO INCLUDE IN VERBATIM
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{S12RESutf.txt}
    1.  \texteng{a-posteriori} μεταβλητότητα = 122.1875
    a-posteriori τυπική απόκλιση =  11.05
    βαθμοί ελευθερίας =    6
    κριτήριο βελτιστοποίησης =   733.1250
    
    2.  OI ΣΥΝΟΡΘΩΜΕΝΕΣ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΙΣ 
    
    σκοπευόμενο  συνορθωμένη  τυπική 
    σημείο       διεύθυνση    απόκλιση 
    (\texteng{grad})      (\texteng{cc})  
    
    22        0.00000      6.38
    32       30.69490      6.38
    42       35.08358      6.38
    2      103.23945      6.38
\end{filecontents}

% The other file used by \attachfile
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{S12RES.txt}
    \texteng{another file} μεταβλητότητα
\end{filecontents}

\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,fleqn]{report}

% PACKAGES
% MAIN
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

% MISC.
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\texteng}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
  \attachfile{S12RES.txt} {\bfseries Αποτελέσματα συνόρθωσης σταθμού 12}
\end{center}
\vspace{3mm}

\section*{\texteng{Using \textbackslash{} and \{ as special characters}}
    
\VerbatimInput[commandchars=\\\{\},baselinestretch=.9]{S12RESutf.txt}


\section*{\texteng{Using + and [ as special characters}}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=+\[\]]
1.  +texteng[a-posteriori] μεταβλητότητα = 122.1875
a-posteriori τυπική απόκλιση =  11.05
βαθμοί ελευθερίας =    6
κριτήριο βελτιστοποίησης =   733.1250

2.  OI ΣΥΝΟΡΘΩΜΕΝΕΣ ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΕΙΣ 

σκοπευόμενο  συνορθωμένη  τυπική 
σημείο       διεύθυνση    απόκλιση 
(+texteng[grad])      (+texteng[cc])  

22        0.00000      6.38
32       30.69490      6.38
42       35.08358      6.38
2      103.23945      6.38
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your method works however it would require me to manually edit all the text files. Thanks for answering my question. I will keep this in mind.